# Twitter share button for website

Tags: angular, twitter, share

I am trying to implement a twitter share button in my website using the following code

```
<a class="btn btn-small" href=" https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=tweetbutton&text={{name}}&url=https://stage.mutterfly.in+{{url}}" >
      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 30px; width:30px; color:black"></i>
</a>
```

where `{{text}}` is coming from api response and {{url}} is from _route.url which is the current url. 
The problem is this link isn't accepting my dynamic data and showing unsafe url error.

How do I insert dynamic text and url into this link and make it work?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value by using a method in the typescript as below,

```
<a class="btn btn-small" 
   [href]="getURL()" >
          <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 30px; width:30px; color:black"></i>
</a>
```

Your method must be as

```
getURL(){
   return "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=tweetbutton&text=this.name&url=https://stage.mutterfly.in+this.url"
}
```

Comment: Why not just a variable? Also, I don't see any TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, i use codeigniter

```
<?php $url_share ="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>

<a style="background-color:#16A7F0;padding:5px;color:#FFF;" class="fa fa-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php echo $product['product_name'];?>&url=<?php echo $url_share;?>&via='$youtTags'" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,height=500,width=600');return false;" > Twitter</a>
```

Comment: I am using Angular2. Can you provide something specific to angular2

Comment: you can change this code to convert in Angular2 from query row_array - 
<?php echo $product['product_name'];?>

Comment: I don't see a PHP tag up there.